# Аppearance of the form, choosing Credit card payment method

Tags: payment-methods, authorize.net

When customer accepts Credit Card (saved) payment method, then appears a form for introducing credit card data. I wonder if it posiible to do the same action (to show this form) if customer accepts other Credit Card payment methods (i.e. Authorize.net option).

Thanks for any help you can provide in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware Authorize.net will provide a credit card form that has all the information needed. [See notes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-payment-gateways-payflow-authorizenet)

If it is simply a styling issue you can simply add your own template or css for this form and style as required.